# Why doesn't outlook.com sync the inbox regularly?

Tags: email, synchronization, outlook.com

I have an old Hotmail email account that I browse using the Outlook.com web interface.

For a very long time now, the web interface no longer syncs with the server to check for new incoming emails. I need to either refresh the tab or change email folders from- and back to- Inbox for new emails to show up.

Hotmail emails do show up on my two Android phones using the provided email client apps (Google's).

I tried using Chrome and Firefox, with and without ad blocker, with and without my Gmail account also configured on the Outlook.com settings, and also tried switching from POP settings to IMAP settings, but the result is the same. Outlook.com refuses to check the server unless forced to manually.

I assumed the problem was with network settings on my computer, but I just changed to a new computer and see the same problem (both PCs are corporate machines).

How can I make Outlook.com sync with the server on a regular basis?

Answer (score 1):

You're relying on Hotmail to *push* email to your PC.

Instead, use a third-party email reader, such as [Thunderbird](https://www.thunderbird.net/en-US/), which polls the Hotmail server at any interval you set, *per account*. However, should the Hotmail server *send* notification, the email reader should also display the message immediately, as shown in the settings below.

[image: Thunderbird Polling Interval]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Although I have thunderbird installed, I use it very rarely for very specific purposes. I want to stick to the web service and looking at a solution for that problem.